# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 105: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, fts3, apsw

My code is pretty much the following :

```
import sqlitefts as fts

connection = apsw.Connection('texts.db', flags=apsw.SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE)
c = connection.cursor()
def do_search(query):
    c.execute('SELECT title, book, author, link, snippet(text_idx) FROM text_idx  WHERE text_idx MATCH 'possumus';') #in this case query='possumus'
    c.fetchall()
--display the results on html--
```

the query works if i search for more than a single word. But when i do single word searches it throws me an decoding error.

Query that doesn't work are similar to the following:

single word searches like -

```
SELECT title, book, author, link, snippet(text_idx) 
FROM text_idx  
WHERE text_idx MATCH 'possumus';
```

and **OR** searches like

```
SELECT title, book, author, link, snippet(text_idx) 
FROM text_idx  
WHERE text_idx MATCH 'quam OR Galliae';
```

The stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ramcharran/phyllo/search/app.py", line 123, in search
    r = do_search(query)
  File "/home/ramcharran/phyllo/search/app.py", line 90, in do_search
    r1 = c.fetchall()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 105: invalid continuation byte
```

The query works fine if I do not use the `snippet()` function in my query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to coding. May be tehere are special characters in the text_idx column
Try to put:

```
# Coding: latin1
```

at the beginning of your file. You must replace latin1 with the encoding that fits your case.
I hope I've helped.

Comment: Hi @Dayana! at the beginning of my application file u mean?

Comment: Yes @Ram Charran, at the begining of your python file.

Comment: and did you try encoding the database as @jyap said?

Answer (score -1):

There might be special characters in your data. Try encoding your database to `utf-8`.